# Java MessageDigest Vs iOS CCHmac-sha256

Tags: java, ios, cryptography

Now I need a help in CCHmac-sha256. I am not getting same output when I am digest the plain text in iOS and Java. Please refer to the below code and guide me to solve this issue.

**iOS Code**

```
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256,cKey,strlen(cKey),cData,strlen(cData),cHMAC);   
NSData *hashedPassword2 = 
    [NSData dataWithBytes:cHMAC length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
```

I am converting this nsdata to base32 string

**Java Code**

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");    
md.update(s1.getBytes());    
byte[] h = md.digest();    
Base32 base32 = new Base32();    
String base32_h = replaceIllegalCharacters(base32.encodeAsString(h));    
System.out.println("\n"+base32_h+"\n");    
String cc1 = base32_h.substring(0, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Java example is performing a SHA-256 hash, not an HMAC.

You need to be using an instance of `Mac` not `MessageDigest`.

Comment: @DuncanJones, your linked example seems to have gone away.

Comment: @Rick Thanks. I've killed off the link. Sounds like the OP needed to look at the iOS code anyway.